# Android bind custom dialog to item (like context menu)

Tags: android, dialog, android-contextmenu

I've created custom dialog and want to bind it to my textview.
I want this dialog to behave like context menu when I click on my textview.

In other words, I don't want this dialog to appear in the center of the screen, but to appear near my textview.

Certainly, I can calculate needed position of this dialog, but as for me, it's not so good way.
I've spent a lot of time searching a way, but unfortunately no result.
Is there some good solution?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that there is [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) in android, which would definitely cover this issue.
[Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example) of usage:
1. Create menu in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_movies"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Movies"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_music"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Music"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_comedy"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Comedy"
        android:visible="true"/>

</menu>
```

2. Basic implementation of Activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_click).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(PopMenuActivity.this, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopMenuActivity.this);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_comedy:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Comedy Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_movies:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Movies Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_music:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Music Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;        
        }
    }
```

3. Result is:
[image]

***That's what I was looking for.***